# How to get last insert id of a record from query builder

Tags: mysql, node.js, query-builder

This is what i am doing to insert record in `mysql` database by using `query-builder`.

```
//Add Schedule
exports.addSchedule = function addSchedule(data){ 

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    db.queryBuilder.insert(tableName, data, (err, res) => {
        if(res){
            console.log(db.queryBuilder.);
            resolve(true);

        }else{
            reject(false);
        }

        console.log(db.queryBuilder.last_query());
    });
 });
}
```

After insertion i need the `insert-id` auto generated key that `mysql insert` created for that record.

I need `insert-id` add record in another table.

Answer (score 2):

Variable `res` contains property `insert_id`, see [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-querybuilder#insert):

```
qb.insert('articles', data, (err, res) => {
  qb.release();
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  const page_data = {
    article_id: res.insert_id,
  }
});
```